# Cookie not being stored in browser even after logging in React Nodejs app deployed on Render

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, express-session

I have built a Full-stack MERN (React + Node.js + MongoDB) application by following this YouTube tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcxjCPeicvU

Project's official **GitHub repo** - https://github.com/codinginflow/MERN-course

After ensuring both frontend and backend apps were working properly on my local machine, I decided to deploy them online. For deploying both frontend and backend, I used [Render](https://render.com/).

I first deployed the backend to Render, and when I tried to connect my **local** frontend app with the **deployed** backend app, it worked great. I could perform actions like **Sign up**/**Log in** without any issues.

Then I deployed my frontend app on Render as well (https://notes-app-xjr0.onrender.com). When I clicked on the above URL, it landed on the Application home page without any issue. Now here comes the interesting part.

Whenever I log in/sign up, the Backend is supposed to store the session, and hence a cookie should be stored in the Frontend to keep the user logged in. Immediately after that, the app makes a `GET` call to the notes API (https://notes-api-ttsn.onrender.com/api/notes) to fetch the notes associated with the user credentials stored in the cookie. But in my case, after successfully logging in (`POST` call to https://notes-api-ttsn.onrender.com/api/users/login) I cannot see the cookie anymore, and hence the notes API is failing with a `401 - User not authenticated` error (screenshot below).

[image: Notes API giving 401 error]
[image: Cookies not available]

**(BACKEND) Express-session and CORS config in `app.ts`**

```
import express from "express"
import session from "express-session";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();

app.use(
  session({
    secret: env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: false,
      sameSite: "none",
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
    },
    rolling: true,
    store: MongoStore.create({
      mongoUrl: env.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING,
    }),
  })
);
app.use(cors({ origin: "*", credentials: true }));
```

**(BACKEND) Login controller function in `controllers/users.ts`**

```
import { RequestHandler } from "express";
import createHttpError from "http-errors";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import UserModel from "../models/User";

interface LoginBody {
  username?: string;
  password?: string;
}

export const login: RequestHandler<unknown, unknown, LoginBody, unknown> = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    if (!username || !password) {
      throw createHttpError(400, "Missing required fields");
    }

    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ username: username })
      .select("+password +email")
      .exec();

    if (!user) {
      throw createHttpError(401, "Invalid username or password!");
    }

    const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!isPasswordValid) {
      throw createHttpError(401, "Invalid username or password!");
    }

    req.session.userId = user._id;

    res.status(201).json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

**(BACKEND) Get Notes controller function in `controllers/notes.ts`**

```
import { RequestHandler } from "express";
import createHttpError from "http-errors";
import NoteModel from "../models/Note";

/* GET ALL NOTES FOR THE LOGGED IN USER */
export const getNotes: RequestHandler = async (req, res, next) => {
  const authenticatedUserId = req.session.userId;

  try {
    const notes = await NoteModel.find({ userId: authenticatedUserId }).exec();
    res.status(200).json(notes);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

**(FRONTEND) Data fetching function in `network/fetchData.ts`**

```
import { ConflictError, UnauthorizedError } from "../errors/http_errors";

export const fetchData = async (input: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit) => {
  const apiEndpoint = env.BACKEND_URL + input;

  const response = await fetch(apiEndpoint, init);
  if (response.ok) {
    return response;
  } else {
    const errorBody = await response.json();
    const { error: errorMessage } = errorBody;

    if (response.status === 401) {
      throw new UnauthorizedError(errorMessage);
    } else if (response.status === 409) {
      throw new ConflictError(errorMessage);
    } else {
      throw Error(
        "Request failed with status : " +
          response.status +
          " message: " +
          errorMessage
      );
    }
  }
};
```

**(FRONTEND) Log in function in `network/user-api.ts`**

```
import { User } from "../models/user";
import { fetchData } from "./fetchData";

export type LoginCredentials = {
  username: string;
  password: string;
};

export const login = async (credentials: LoginCredentials): Promise<User> => {
  const response = await fetchData("/api/users/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
  });

  return response.json();
};
```

**(FRONTEND) Notes fetching function in `network/note-api.ts`**

```
import { Note } from "../models/note";
import { fetchData } from "./fetchData";

/* GET ALL NOTES FOR THE LOGGED IN USER */
export const fetchNotes = async (): Promise<Note[]> => {
  const response = await fetchData("/api/notes", { method: "GET" });

  return response.json();
};
```

Comment: Did you fix this? I am getting the same problem with render.com

Comment: Hi Javier, yes I fixed it by searching the internet and including various changes in my code as directed. However, I don't know for sure which of these changes are necessary and which of them are redundant. Below are the changes I made - if you figure out which change is responsible for the app working again, please let me know.

Comment: **BACKEND**  
1. `app.ts`  

* `app.set("trust proxy", 1);` (insert below `const app = express()`)  
* Bringing CORS settings (`app.use(cors({ origin: FRONTEND_URL, credentials: true }))`) below the above line

Comment: 2. `notes.ts`  
* Adding the below before sending res.json()  
  - `req.session.save();`

Comment: 3. `users.ts`  
* Adding the below before `res.status().json()` 
  - `req.session.save((err) => console.log(err));`

Comment: **FRONTEND**  
1. `notes_api.ts` and `user_api.ts`
* Added `credentials: "include",` option in every `fetch` API call -
`const response = await fetchData("/api/notes", {
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "include",
  });`

Comment: Thanks, at the end I gave up as I understood that without a custom domain I could not set cookies with render.com

Comment: Hi Javier, I didn't use a custom domain with render.com, yet it worked fine.

Comment: Then I do not know what I had wrong...maybe in future I give it another try... thank you for the help by the way!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with using cookies when deployed with render.

From this [resource](https://community.render.com/t/cookie-doesnt-send-to-browser/10136). Render deploys your backend server with this subdomain "onrender.com".
It’s a listed public suffix so **cookies** can’t be shared across different subdomains - if you were to using your own sub-domain might resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
```

Adding this worked in my case.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work